# How do name-lookup and operator-overload work?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading, name-lookup

I want to output some private library `class ns::A` to the `plog`, so I add the `operator <<` overload to `ns::A`.

The following code cannot be compiled.

```
error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostringstream’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char>’} and ‘const ns::A’)
     out << t;
     ~~~~^~~~
```

But changing the namespace `other` to `ns`, `plog`, `plog::detail` or `std` can make the compiling error go away, why?
The `std::cout<<` and `std::ostringstream<<` works fine anyway.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

namespace plog {
namespace detail {}
struct Record {
  template <typename T>
  Record& operator<<(const T& t) {
    using namespace plog::detail;

    out << t;
    return *this;
  }
  std::ostringstream out;
};
}

namespace ns {
struct A {};
}

namespace other {}

namespace other { // changing other to ns, plog, plog::detail or std will fix compiling error
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ns::A& a) { return os; }
}

int main() {
  ns::A a;
  using namespace plog;
  using namespace plog::detail;
  using namespace ns;
  using namespace other;
  std::cout << a;
  std::ostringstream oss;
  oss << a;
  plog::Record s;
  s << a; // compiling error
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: [This name lookup reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup) might be helpful. Especially the section about [argument-dependent lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

Comment: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostringstream’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char>’} and ‘const ns::A’)
     out << t;
     ~~~~^~~~

Comment: `using namespace other;` apply to `main` scope, Doesn't apply to Record& operator<<(const T& t).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you `main`:

```
int main() {
  ns::A a;
  using namespace plog;
  using namespace plog::detail;
  using namespace ns;
  using namespace other;
  std::cout << a;
  std::ostringstream oss;
  oss << a;
  plog::Record s;
  s << a; // compiling error
}
```

Your `using namespace` only applies to `main`'s scope and doesn't "propagate" (to `plog::Record::operator<< (const T& t)`).

Then `s << a;` would call `plog::Record::operator<< (const T& t)` with `T` = `ns::A`.

So, in

```
Record& operator<<(const T& t)
{
    using namespace plog::detail;

    out << t;
    return *this;
}
```

`out << t;` (with `T` = `ns::A`) will look at namespace (With ADL):

- global namespace
- namespace `plog` (`plog::Record`)
- namespace `plog::detail` (`using namespace plog::detail;`)
- namespace `std`  (`std::ostringstream out`)
- namespace `ns`   (`ns::A`)

`other::operator<<` is not considered, and you don't have valid match, so compile error.